# Azure virtual network hybrid connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I've got an Azure Virtual Network setup and a VM setup within the network. I've installed the Hybrid Connection Manager app on the VM.

I also have an Azure App Service and I've created a hybrid connection between it and the VM and they are both claiming they are happily connected to each other.

Also on the VM I've installed an app that is listening on http://localhost:1234

Can someone tell me what IP I use from my app service to talk to http://localhost:1234 on the VM? e.g. Is it [VM internal IP]:1234 or [VM public IP]:1234, or something else. Nothing is talking at the moment so I want to make sure the IP address is not the problem.

Comment: Try to assign a dns name to your VM and use that from App Service as using IPs is not always an apt solution if you are using dynamic IPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the computer name of the VM. For example, call to `SQLSRV009:1234` from your code in App Service. The Hybrid Connection definition in the portal should reflect the same name (same as computer name, same as what you're calling from your code).

Check out this well written guide for the full picture —
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage

> It is possible to set a Hybrid Connection endpoint to an IP address. **If you use an IP address, you may or may not reach the on-premises resource, depending on your client.**
>
> The Hybrid Connection depends on the client doing a DNS lookup. In most cases, the client is your application code. **If the client does not perform a DNS lookup**, (it does not try to resolve the IP address as if it were a domain name (x.x.x.x)), **then traffic is not sent through the Hybrid Connection.**
>
> For example (pseudocode), you define 10.4.5.6 as your on-premises host:
>   The following scenario works:
>   `Application code -> GetHostByName("10.4.5.6") -> Resolves to 127.0.0.3 -> Connect("127.0.0.3") -> Hybrid Connection -> on-prem host`
>
> The following scenario doesn't work:
>   `Application code -> Connect("10.4.5.6") -> ?? -> No route to host`

Also make your app listen on either `0.0.0.0` or the private IP since i'm not terribly sure `localhost` will work with HC.

Why not use VNET integration for the Web App? All you need to do is create a route based (IKEv2) VPN gateway in the VNET, like so — 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm reading through the link now. I've tried public IP, local IP and computer name, none seem to get through. I've tried opening up all firewalls and I am then able to use a browser to navigate to the public IP, but the route via the hybrid connection is still unsuccessful. I'm not using VNET-VNET via IKEv2 as I already have an IKEv1 connection set up on the VNET to talk to a third party service that requires IKEv1,

Comment: Remove all HC setup and start over. That usually fixes it. This technology has been around for a while now and it works, i have many HCs in production as i'm typing this. You don't need to open up any firewall port (inbound) as all HC connectivity from the VM is initiated outbound.

Comment: There's another option, expose your service as public endpoint on the VM and NSG the hell out of it, only allowing traffic from the outbound IP addresses of the App Service Plan - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/ IMPORTANT! It's not just you using those IPs so make sure you have an authN/authZ layer on top of your service if you do that.

Comment: The App Service itself is in an ASE with its own DNS server. I've added the VM computername/IP to the DNS entries (not sure this is the right thing to do) and created an outbound NSG rule to allow all :1234 traffic out. But still no luck on the routing.

Comment: I've fixed it. This was due to me using an IP Address for the Hybrid Connection endpoint rather than the computer name (I was using the computer name to actually connect my app to the service hosted on the VM), but when I created the hybrid connection I entered the IP for the host at that point.

Comment: ASE? But ASE already sits in a Virtual Network, no need for HC or VPN. Just call the VM on its private IP address (make sure it's a reserved one so it doesn't change). Or is it a different VNET you're trying to call into? There's VNET peering for that and it's just a matter of a few clicks. HC is good, but solution of least complexity should always win.

Comment: Yes, it's a different VNET. I've not seen VNET peering, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `VM host name`, thanks for evilSnobu's [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage) .

> If you use an IP address, you may or may not reach the on-premises
>   resource, depending on your client.

If you use `VM public IP`, traffic packets are transmitted over the Internet to your VM not VPN tunnel. `localhost` only could be used inside VM.

Also, if your app is listening on `localhost(127.0.0.1)`, the service only could access inside your VM. As evilSnobu said, you need modify your service listening on `0.0.0.0` or `private IP(like 10.0.0.4)`. You could check with following command.

For Linux

```
netstat -ant|grep 1234
```

For Windows

```
netstat -ant|findstr 1234
```

Comment: But don't use the IP address for Hybrid Connection, use the hostname/computername - as noted here in the 2nd IMPORTANT box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage

Comment: @evilSnobu Thanks for you link, I update  my answer.